# Prevent full page reloading on navigation ASP.net MVC 5.xx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

At the start of the develoment, i was able to navigate from a page to another in my website, without having the full page reloading. For unknown reason, after a day of development, i can no longer navigate between page without layout flickering / full page reloading.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Vertikal Elagage</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/materialize/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a9869f94dd.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
    @*<div id="navbar_header" class="navbar_header"></div>*@
    <div id="navbar_fixed" class="navbar-fixed navbar_padding">
        <nav class="nav-extended">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Index" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Accueil", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "tab" })</li>
                    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "About" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Qui sommes-nous ?", "About", "Home", null, new { @class = "tab" })</li>
                    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Pruning" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Elagage", "Pruning", "Home", null, new { @class = "tab" })</li>
                    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Felling" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Abbatage", "Felling", "Home", null, new { @class = "tab" })</li>
                    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Landscaping" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Paysagisme", "Landscaping", "Home", null, new { @class = "tab" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Galerie", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />

    </div>
    <footer class="layout_footer">
        <div class="row mb-0">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 p-2 p-md-3 d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
                <h4>Social</h4>
                <p>Suivez nous sur les réseaux sociaux pour prendre connaissance de nos projets et chantiers sur l'île !</p>
                <p>Vous pourrez y voir nos dernières réalisations, avec des photos comparatives !</p>
                <div class="row mt-4 mt-md-0">
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 p-md-3 d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
                        <div class="social_round">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook-f social_icon"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="social_round">
                            <i class="fa fa-instagram social_icon"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="social_round">
                            <i class="fa fa-twitter social_icon"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 p-2 p-md-3 d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
                <h4>Horaires</h4>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-90 w-md-50 opening_time_container">
                    <p class="opening_time">Lundi-jeudi</p>
                    <p>07h00 - 17h00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-90 w-md-50 opening_time_container">
                    <p class="opening_time">Vendredi</p>
                    <p>07h00 - 16h00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-90 w-md-50 opening_time_container">
                    <p class="opening_time">Samedi</p>
                    <p>08h00 - 12h00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 p-2 p-md-3 d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
                <h4>Contact</h4>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-90 opening_time_container">
                    <p class="opening_time">Adresse</p>
                    <p>Piton saint-leu</p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-90 w-md-50 opening_time_container">
                    <p class="opening_time">Téléphone</p>
                    <p>+262 692 92 64 77</p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-90 w-md-50 opening_time_container">
                    <p class="opening_time">Email</p>
                    <p>velluetl@gmail.com</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Lucas Velluet  Vertikal Elagage 974 La Réunion</span>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
  @*  <script src="~/Scripts/customScript.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
</body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out what did i changed to break the normal behavior i had (only body re-rendering) from the template at the beggining.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. You were always getting a full page load but didn't notice until now.

Comment: Im 100% sure that the layout wasnt re-rendering. Actually, it blinks everytime i navigate between pages

Comment: MVC does full page rendering. That's just how it works.

Comment: @Crowcoder full page rendering you meant ? Any idea how to render the view only, not reloading everytime the layout ? I found solution, but onluy with partial views, and quite complicated

Comment: When I need to do Single Page App type behavior in MVC I create View Components for the content I want to replace on the page without a refresh. I return them from a controller and use javascript to replace the innerHTML of whatever I need. You can also use a client-side framework like Vue if you prefer. I suggest if you have the choice, next time use a SPA framework instead of MVC.